# Is there a way to convert slim fixture fitnesse test scripts to karate test scripts?

Tags: migration, karate, fitnesse-slim

We have a lot of test scripts written in fitnesse using SLIM fistures. Now we want to adopt karate framework. Is there a way to migrate easily those test scripts to karate test scripts? That would reduce a lot of effort.

Example of a Slim fixture test script :

```
*!
!***> !style_blue [1) Rule-PG Assignment Creation]

!***> Create Dataset(s)

!***> DS1 Iv Type is CS
!define Index {1}
!define DatasetName {CS_FUT_dataset}

!|Hds ConditionSet Details                                                                                                                    |
|ConditionsetId|ConditionId|Condition|ConditionOperator|RhsType|RhsValues|IncludeNull|Direction|Operator|Percentage|Delink|URE          |Level|
|1             |1          |${IvType}|=                |Scalar |CS,FUT   |           |         |        |          |      |DIRECT or URE|All  |

!include -c .FrontPage.IceEndToEndRegressionSuite.TemplatesSuite.RuleConstruct.HoldingsDatasetCreationTemplate
*!

!***> Test Category Dataset
!include -c .FrontPage.IceEndToEndRegressionSuite.TemplatesSuite.RuleConstruct.PreDefinedGroupByTemplates.GroupBy_MasterIssuer
*!
```

Comment: can you point to an example of what this SLIM fixtures look like ?

Comment: Shared a small sample of a test case in the query.

Comment: I'll be honest, I don't think it is possible. note that you can cut and paste JSON into Karate tests and that should save a lot of time. if it is possible to record HTTP traffic using some kind of proxy and export HAR files - there may be options to convert those to Karate tests using a commercial tool